# Orbeon Forms: Change Style in and Action

Tags: orbeon

Sorry again for the simple question..

How can I change the background colour of a ***text box*** or an ***explanatory text box*** in a action?

Many thanks in advance.

PeteA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your own CSS ([doc](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/styling/css)), write a rule so that if your text box or explanatory text where to have a given CSS class of your choice on it, say `highlight`, then it would get the required background color.
2. In the control settings for that text box or explanatory text, under custom CSS classes, use an XPath value template to produce the `highlight` class only when a certain condition is met, say `{'highlight'[//total > 100]}`, which would add the class `highlight` if the value of the field `total` is above 100.
3. If you can't directly determine whether the class should be added or not based on other values in the form, and you really needs to run an action, then have that action set the value of hidden field that you use in your XPath value template in step two.

Comment: Hi Alex,
I have set my own CSS (.red and .green) in the STYLE section in this form: https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/7cf4e4aac90aa717adaeeaa21009bd6a7deb55be
But I still cannot get your suggestion above to work.
I simple need to check if the value is a PASS or FAIL, and change the background colour accordingly.
As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.
PeteA

Comment: Alex,
I tried the "highlight" option above in the following link, but it didnt appear to work:
https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/7cf4e4aac90aa717adaeeaa21009bd6a7deb55be
PeteA

Comment: Excellent Pete, and I'm glad you managed to avoid using an action (sometimes, the simpler the better!), and thank you for the update.

Answer (score 2):

Solved: I used the following syntax in the ***Custom CSS Classes*** field:

{if (//PoWRA_Q1 = 'yes') then 'green' else 'red'}

Many thanks Alex for pointing me in the right direction

PeteA